# can we enforce restrictions on jaxb globalbindings for mapping xs:dateTime to java.util.Date

Tags: java, jaxb

I have 3 schemas, each has xs:dateTime. To represent xs:dateTime as java.util.Date in java jaxb objects, i am using binding.xjb which looks as below

```
<bindings schemaLocation="schema1.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
        <package name="com.mycompany.ims.schema1" />
    </schemaBindings>
</bindings> 
<bindings schemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
        <package name="com.mycompany.ims.schema2" />
    </schemaBindings>
</bindings> 
<bindings schemaLocation="schema3.xsd">
    <schemaBindings>
        <package name="com.mycompany.ims.schema3" />
    </schemaBindings>
</bindings>     

 <globalBindings>
    <javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
      parseMethod="com.mycompany.ims.utils.JaxbDateAdapter.parseDateTime"
      printMethod="com.mycompany.ims.utils.JaxbDateAdapter.printDateTime"
    />
    <javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date"
      parseMethod="com.mycompany.ims.utils.JaxbDateAdapter.parseDate"
      printMethod="com.mycompany.ims.utils.JaxbDateAdapter.printDate"
    />
</globalBindings>
```

If i generate jaxb objects, all the xs:dateTime elements are represeted as java.util.Date.
I have a requirement where in one of the schema (say schema1.xsd) i donot want to represent the xs:dateTime element as java.util.Date.

Is there any way i can configure to restrict for particular schema or based on node name? Can any one help.

I resolved the issue by adding the below xjb configuration, I edited the post to help the people who faced the same problem like mine

```
<bindings schemaLocation="schema1.xsd">
    <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='ApplicationHeader1']">
        <bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='CreDt']">
          <javaType name="java.util.Date" 
          parseMethod="com.mycompany.ims.utils.JaxbDateAdapter.parseUTCDateTime"
          printMethod="com.mycompany.ims.utils.JaxbDateAdapter.printUTCDateTime"
            />
        </bindings>
    </bindings> 
    <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='ApplicationHeaderV01']">
        <bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='CreDt']">
          <javaType name="java.util.Date" 
          parseMethod="com.mycompany.ims.utils.JaxbDateAdapter.parseUTCDateTime"
          printMethod="com.mycompany.ims.utils.JaxbDateAdapter.printUTCDateTime"
            />
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use different binding files for different schemas.  Use one for schema1.xsd which doesn't have the xs:dateTime customisation, and another for the other schema which does have it in.

Comment: At the moment all files(schema1.xsd, schema2.xsd, schema3.xsd, binding.xjb) are in the same folder and i'm generating the jaxb objects using maven plugin

Comment: @nagendra: So either move them into different directories, or tell the maven plugin to use a different binding file for each schema, or stop using maven. One of those options must be possible.